pytestarch rule fails saying that "moduleA" which is imported by "moduleB" using as an aliased relative import is not imported
Label Type: question
Issue Type: Request for clarification
Environment
Linux Mint 21.3 (kernel 5.15.0-117-generic), running Python 3.10.12 using pytestarch == 3.0.1
Background

My project path is /home/developer/python/snakes-and-ladders-engine and it has the folder structure:

├── src
│   ├── game
│   │   └──  game.py
│   └── utils
│       └── gameutilities.py
└── tests
    └──  architecture
        └── test_architecture.py


The gameutilities.py module contains only methods - no classes are defined in the file.

game.py imports gameutilities.py as


from ..utils import gameutilities as GameUtilities


In test_architecture.py, a pytest fixture returns an evaluable architecture.

@pytest.fixture
def game_architecture_instance(project_root: Path, src_root: Path) -> EvaluableArchitecture:
    return get_evaluable_architecture(str(project_root), str(src_root))

Question
I am trying to define the rule "gameutilities should be imported by game" using a pytest test.
def test_utilities_invocation_rule(game_architecture_instance:  EvaluableArchitecture) -> None:
    utils_name: str = "snakes-and-ladders-engine.src.utils.gameutilities"
    game_name: str = "snakes-and-ladders-engine.src.game.game"

    utilities_invocation_rule: Rule = (
        Rule().modules_that()
        .are_named(utils_name)
        .should_only().be_imported_by_modules_that()
        .are_named(game_name)
    )

    utilities_invocation_rule.assert_applies(game_architecture_instance)

This fails with the result
AssertionError: "snakes-and-ladders-engine.src.utils.gameutilities" is not imported by "snakes-and-ladders-engine.src.game.game".

Other functional tests under the test tree work fine, and only the architecture test seems to be failing.
Is the rule misconfigured? What am I doing wrong here? Any support on how to fix this error is much appreciated.

It turns out the relative import
from ..utils import gameutilities as GameUtilities

was causing the problem.
I changed it to an absolute import
(import src.utils.gameutilities as GameUtilities)
and the architecture tests worked fine.
